# Using "of" or apostrophe, which is more common?

Tags: difference, possessives, style

Sometimes when I write, for example, "the boundaries of segments", I am suggested to use "segments' boundaries" or even "segment boundaries".

Or "the page's content" vs. "the content of the page" vs. "the page content". Then I would like to know is it always preferred to use phrases with apostrophe or adjective?

For example

> In our terms, they are mainly textual elements within the page content, which serve as **the starting point  of a data region (or a data region's starting point ?)**  or a distinctive feature within it

Comment: Have you looked through existing answers for similar questions?  It seems that in my brief time here I already encountered a discussion on possessive vs noun as adjective.

Answer (score 3):

Nouns in possessive case, genitive case, and attributive noun-noun constructs can look similar, some can be substituted for one another, can even have very similar meaning, yet they do differ.

In most case, at least as I understand it, genitive case (*noun1* **of** *noun2*) can often be expressed by "*noun2 noun1*" construct, in which *noun2* plays the *attributive* role.  For instance,

> **A lover *of* dogs** (a person who admires canines) -->
>   **A *dog* lover** (*dog* is attributive)

or

> **An engine *of* a car** (that hunk of metal under the hood) -->
>   **A car engine** (*car* is attributive)

Proper nouns can be attributive ("**Moscow streets**" = "**streets *of* Moscow**" "***Canada* geese**", although not "**geese *of* Canada**").

Possessive case is used to indicate exclusive ownership (of an instance or of a class), authorship, etc.

> Newton'**s** laws of physics
>   Ferma'**s** Theorem
>   Obama'**s** presidency
>   StoneB'**s** answer to your question on ELL

As far as your question goes, if we take the two specific examples, we see that

> **a data region's starting point** -- is completely the same as
>   **the starting poitn *of* a data region**

*because* every data region has the starting point, and that point has only one responsibility - to start the data region, so it's exclusive to data regions in general and to each data region in particular.

You could say

> a data region starting point

in which case "*data region*" becomes attributive, which describes the *starting point*, but in your situation I think it is less desirable because, first, hard to judge to what the indefinite article applies (a data region? a starting point?), and second, it *implies* that there can be several "*starting points*" and one (or maybe several) have the attribute "data region".  In reality it's a data region in which you're probably interested foremost.

Let's look at *page content*.  You can say

> **the content *of* the page** -- that would be the same as
>   **the page content**

and everybody knows that you're talking about *content* whose main (for now anyway) attribute is that it represents a page.  It doesn't **belong** to it, though, according to that phrase.  But what if you write

> **the page's content** -- is that so wrong?

No, it's perfectly alright because the content cannot belong to anything *but* the page (of which it is the content).  So those three are interchangeable, I believe.

As to "**segment boundaries**" and "**segment's boundaries**" (no, "segments boundaries" is non-grammatical), there is a difference in meaning.  The former means "*boundaries **between** segments*" whereas the latter mean "*boundaries **of a single** segment*" (its own boundaries, not necessarily involving other segments).

Knowing the terms now (Possessive/Genitive Case, Attributive noun) you can find more information on those online, like [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) on [elsewhere](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/111108possattrib.htm).

Comment: Thank you, then you mean in each case one of them is preferred? for example "page content" to the others? and in possessives if there is no emphasis I think apostrophe is more common. right?!

Comment: There is no general rule like that.  Every case is different.

Comment: This is not a rule by any means, but in my own writing I avoid using `'s` with inanimate nouns. Just personal preference.