# A baby's smile vs the smile of a baby

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

**A baby's smile** is the most invaluable thing in the world;

**The smile of a baby** is the most invaluable thing in the world

Are both sentences grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "of" or apostrophe, which is more common?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65472/using-of-or-apostrophe-which-is-more-common) See also [Apostrophes for possession: nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69661/apostrophes-for-possession-nouns)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are grammatical and idiomatic.  "A baby's smile" is more common per Google's [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby%27s%20smile%2Csmile%20of%20a%20baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaby%20%27s%20smile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmile%20of%20a%20baby%3B%2Cc0)